# Android RelativeLayout doesn't stretch to fill parent's height

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Motorolla XOOM, Android 3.2. After my resource preloader(you can see a progressbar of it on the picture below) has finished his work, this window shows up, but it's height is not stretched to fill all screen. How can it be fixed?

Image: http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/1523/device20120319140942.png

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/derp"
            android:text="@string/continue_text"
            android:textColor="@color/main_red"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/continue_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/derp"
            android:text="@string/playGame"
            android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/play"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/derp"
            android:text="@string/leaderboard"
            android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/leaderboard"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/derp"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/settings"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/derp"
            android:text="@string/closeGame"
            android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_layout"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/main_red"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you call it directly (with setContentView()) or you iflate it?

Comment: dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try with this code

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/button_layout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/continue_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:background="@drawable/derp"
           android:text="@string/continue_text"
           android:textColor="#ff0000"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/play"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_below="@id/continue_button"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/derp"
           android:text="@string/playGame"
           android:textColor="#ff0000"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_below="@id/play"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/derp"
           android:text="@string/leaderboard"
           android:textColor="#ff0000"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/settings"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_below="@id/leaderboard"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/derp"
           android:text="@string/settings"
           android:textColor="#ff0000"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/exit"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_below="@id/settings"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/derp"
           android:text="@string/closeGame"
           android:textColor="#ff0000"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/version"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_below="@id/button_layout"
       android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
       android:text="TextView"
       android:textColor="#ff0000"
       android:textSize="14dp" />
   ```

this code working for me

If this is also not working you have to use weight concept

Correct code check this xml file linearlayout missing in the top entry

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/add_pic">


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:gravity="center">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/nickname" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/button_layout"
            android:text="TextView" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/button_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <Button android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/derp"
                android:text="@string/continue_text" android:textColor="#ff0000"
                android:textSize="30dp" android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/play" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_below="@id/continue_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/derp" android:text="@string/playGame"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/leaderboard" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_below="@id/play"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/derp" android:text="@string/leaderboard"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/settings" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_below="@id/leaderboard"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/derp" android:text="@string/settings"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/exit" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_below="@id/settings"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/derp" android:text="@string/closeGame"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/version" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/button_layout" android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="TextView" android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textSize="14dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```